# Fill an Image with white color to have square dimensions

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick

Let's say I have an Image of 300 x 500 (width x height) pixels.

Now I need to generate an image with square dimensions of it.

Instead of cropping the image, I want to fill the missing space with white color.

In this example the with should be filled by 200 pixels (100 pixels on each side so the image is in the middle) so that the Image would be 500 x 500 px.

If it was opposite (500 x 300) the same should happen but with the height.

I have almost no experience in using imagemagick so how could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Imagick::borderImage()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.borderimage.php)!

Example for your case of filling 100px left and right each:

```
// let's assume that $im is your image object
$color=new ImagickPixel();
$color->setColor("white");
$im->borderImage($color,100,0);
```

Comment: Good solution but not perfect. When I have a picture with the dimensions 650x365 I cannot match the 650 because borderImage adds at least 2 pixels on each side (top and bottom or left and right). If I try to match that the closest I can get is 650x649 or 650x651, any way to fix this?

Comment: nvm, I used crop to fix it.